# Python code that start a code in a python file at some specific time

Tags: python, time, schedule

I want to execute a file at a specific time as I won't be around at that time to execute it.

I was thinking if there is a way in which I can write some code in another file, that will start that code, and leave it running so that it can start that code at that specific time - Maybe using os and time, or command line.

Comment: You could do something like this but is there any reason to not just use task scheduling methods your OS has?

Comment: @JonClements, there is no reason, but I was looking at different ways I can execute this task, I am new to coding and I was wondering if this could be done

Comment: Python has a builtin [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) module and there's plenty of 3rd party ones such as [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - but seriously - apart from knowing you can do it and it being a good thought experiment, then go for the features your OS provides to do it for any real world purpose.

Comment: You can use Cron-tab for scheduling a python file. It's easy and efficient.

Comment: Yes, you can. Please see [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
import time, subprocess, sys
time.sleep(3600)  # wait 1 hour
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'another-script.py'])
```

Comment: right, this makes it even simpler. Thank you so much

Comment: @SupreetSingh not that it really matters in this case but feel I should point out that this means you're going to have a Python process occupying memory while it's sleeping... while using the OS functionality you won't... It also means that if you have to restart the computer before the task has run, you have to remember to also re-run this so it runs what you wanted... while again, with the OS approach, it'll still have it queued to run...

Comment: I see, your points are vaild. Can you link me to a video or something where I can use to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's builtin [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) module:

```
import sched, time

def action():
    print("hello world")

# Set up scheduler
s = sched.scheduler(time.localtime, time.sleep)
# Schedule when you want the action to occur
s.enterabs(time.strptime('Tue March 15 15:55:17 2020'), 0, action)
# Block until the action has been run
s.run()
```